# How can I determine the size of the text inside of a UITextField INCLUDING the cursor?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to know the exact size of the the text in a textField so that I can make it larger if it exceeds it's initial smaller size.

This code seems to work, except it doesn't include the space created by the cursor.

```
let textsize = (self.textField.text as NSString)
    .size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self.textField.font as Any])
```

Is there any way to know how much space the cursor account for?

Comment: "... except it doesn't include the space created by the cursor." Do you mean that it doesn´t count the cursor width or what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, the NSString.size(attributes:) function doesn't count the cursor width because it isn't included in the UITextField.text property

Comment: Okey, why not just add 2 pixels to `textSize.width`?

Comment: That is what I am currently resorting to, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: That´s how I have done it so far and it works. I answered that so that others can benefit from it in the future too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSString.size(attributes:)` does not count the the size of the cursor, it only calculates the characters. So what you could do is to add `x`
pixels to your `textSize.width` as a workaround.

Comment: 2 pixels is not enough in my case.  I think the cursor size might differ depending on the font size.

Comment: @BRoyDawson great. Updated the answer.